# Sound is coming out both in speaker and bluetooth earphones after end a call after using a call app

Tags: android, xiaomi, miui

I have a bug after updating to MIUI 14.0.1 my redmi note 10 pro

After end a call using any social media calling app like whatsapp or IMO. All media sounds are playing on both speakers and bluetooth earphones.

I searched on web about this issue. Some people confirmed that after re-installing the software update by using Download package option in updater. But I can't use the option after pressing download package option It is showing "can't download update wait a minute or two".

Please help me to fix this bu
g.

But I can't use the option after pressing download package option It is showing "can't download update wait a minute or two".